# Changing App from Ionic to Native

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play

Okay so 2 years ago I was just a web developer with no real knowledge about mobile app development so I decided to go with ionic when I was asked to develop the app.  2 years later I can now code in java and I've been asked to build a native version of the same app which I have done successfully.

Now this is my problem, it is time for my app to be released on the play store but I am unable to add a new update because the current version was signed with a different certificate than what I used with ionic 2 years ago.

Now I managed to locate my old ionic project with the .keystore file however I am unable to use it to sign my android app because I do not remember the alias neither do I remember the password.

So this is my question now, what do I do? Is there a way of recovering or changing the old alias and password? Is there a way for me to publish this new release as an update to the old one even though it is signed with a different certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. Each Android app has an unique signing key, and when you publish the first APK to Google Play, the key hash is registered as a security mechanism: even if someone hacks your Google Play Developer Account and posts a new hacked APK, this APK won't be accepted unless it was signed with the same key as the first one published. Google Play refuses new APKs signed with different Keys.